# Recommend an Arduino Uno shield to monitor the state of 5 DPDT electrical switches

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, switch

I have a project where I need to monitor the state of 5 DPDT electrical switches with Arduino Uno. Also, the Arduino board will be measuring the output from 3 thermocouples on 3 of the analogue pins as input and sending signals to open and close 3 relays for heaters on the 3 of the digital pins as output. The data with the state of the microswitches and the measurements from the thermocouples will be send over a serial connection to a PC.

I think I need a shield with at least 20 inputs for monitoring the 5 DPDT electrical switches (5 x 2 x 2). The common of the switches will be connected to a common rail. Can I use an I2C extension shield for this purpose? Is this going to create an issue with the serial connection? Any specific shield recommendations?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Do you have 5 switches that you want to wire to an Arduino, or do you have some existing system which has 5 switches and you need to monitor the state of those switches?

Comment: Hi, the system is not yet built it is something that is being planned. I will have 5 DPDT switches that I want to wire to an Arduino. My question is on monitoring the state of the switches, because there are not enough pins on the Arduino Uno, and I do not have much experience with extensions shields. I wrote about the TC and the relays, so that it is clear that I will be using also 3 analogue and 3 digital pins on the board for another purpose.

Comment: Unless they are on-off-on switches you only need one input per switch - so 5 inputs.

Comment: 1 DPDT switch has 2 NC, 2 NO and 2 COM pins, I think I need 4 pins for the 2 NC and 2 NO, the 2 COM are going to be connected to a common rail.

Comment: Just because there are two switches ganged together it doesn't mean you have to read them both. If you know the switch is in one position you also know it isn't in the other. Thus you only need one input. Common to ground, one side of the switch to input. Input to Vcc through resistor (or internal pullup). Just like any other switch. You're over-complicating it. Ignore 4 of the 6 connections - they are completely meaningless.

Comment: Have you found a way to make the two Poles of a DPDT switch be in different states? Or have you found a way for the direction that a DPDT switch to be Thrown in to be more than two choices?

Comment: Hi, I want to check the state on the 2 NC and 2 NO, I know that if DPDT switch is turned this changes the state for both circuits from one to another. However the reallity is that sometimes DPDT get a faulty circuit, the DPDT turns but only one of the circuits switches, because the other is faulty. Also there are cases of open circuit in switch connections, so if a i.e. NC is turned to NO, the NC circuits opens, but the NO is not closed and the other way around. I want to get the state of all contacts, so that I am sure the switches turned and that they do not have faulty circuits.

Comment: Those kind of failures only really happen from contact arcing - something you will never see with an Arduino.

Comment: what will the relays switch? (voltage, current, ac/dc)

Comment: The relays are SRD-05VDC-SL-C and will switch 230 AC voltage. They are on a board with other components. The board is powered by 12 V adapter and has input pins for the Arduino. The DPDT switches will switch low current signal.

Answer (score 0):

If you're really set on measuring the state of every single connection of every single switch (though I still don't see the need) then yes, you'll need 20 IO connections.

You could create those with IO expanders (MCP23017 for example), or you could use multiplexing.

Instead of 4x5 (20) IO pins you'd instead need 2+10 (12) IO pins.

Treat all the "Common" connections as the rows of a keypad and all the NC and NO connections as the columns of a keypad. Add a smattering of diodes to isolate everything, and you can then scan through the switches one at a time checking each of the two switch states.

You can read more about keypad matrices [here](https://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=14175).

Comment: Thank you, I will try with MCP23017.

Comment: @Iliya They provide 16 IO, so you will need two of them. They can be chained together though.

Comment: Consider posting your schematic, not a frizzy thing showing all connections. On the switches just show a few of them so we understand what is happening.